# how to use two line of b:if with the same content

Tags: html, xml, templates, blogger

Hello I hope that you are fine and safe

my question is how to use two line of b:if with the same content like this code

```
`<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;static_page&quot;'>
<style>
//my code//
</style>
</b:if>
</b:if>`
```

when i add this line like it displayed it doens't work for me so any help please and Thanks
i want to add the same content with two line of b:if in blogger template the code that i paste it doens't work for me so what i should add between them Thanks